# How can we think of Krishna if we haven't seen him?

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita

Krishna says in Gita that [always think of him ,](https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/9/verse/34) but we haven't seen Krishna , how can we think of him ?

Also Gita was in reality told to Arjun , who has seen Krishna .
Is this also applicable to everyone ?

Gita 9:34

> Always think of Me, be devoted to Me, worship Me, and offer obeisance to Me. Having dedicated your mind and body to Me, you will certainly come to Me.

Comment: The same way that we think of all other deities that we may not have seen. For that matter, it needn't even be a deity. I have never seen Gandhiji, but I've heard of him, I've seen depictions of him, and I've heard stories about him and his actions. Were you to ask me to think of him, then, I could easily do so. In the same way, I can do so with Krishna (see also: https://www.krishna.com/why-cant-we-see-krishna)

Answer (score 1):

> Also Gita was in reality told to Arjun , who has seen Krishna . Is this also applicable to everyone ?

Yes, it is applicable to everyone. As per 18.78:

> **18.78. Wherever there is the Lord of Yoga (Krishna) and Arjuna, the archer, there will be splendour, victory, wealth, and goodness, I am certain.**

This means that they are accessible outside of the dialogue that comprises the Gita. This was the purpose of the Gita - so that it *could* be accessible for everyone. It is why we even know of the dialogue even though we were not there when it happened.

> Krishna says in Gita that always think of him , but we haven't seen Krishna , how can we think of him ?

With the above understanding, Krishna is not limited. Bearing this in mind, he can be thought of without being recognised. Also, Krishna himself says,

> **10.32. Of creations I am the beginning and the end, and also the middle, O Arjuna. Of all knowledge, the knowledge of the supreme Self.**
>
> **10.39-40. And also I am that which is the seed of all creatures, Arjuna. There is nothing that could exist without existing through Me, whether moving or not moving. There is no end to My divine manifestations, Arjuna.**
>
> **11.8. But you are not able to see Me with your own eyes. I give to you a divine eye; behold My majestic power!**
>
> **11.54. By undistracted devotion alone can I be known and be truly seen in this form, and be entered into, Arjuna.**
>
> **14.26. And he who serves Me With the yoga of unswerving devotion, transcending these qualities (three gunas), is ready for absorption in Brahman.**
>
> **14.27. For I am the abode of Brahman, of the immortal and the imperishable, of everlasting virtue, and of absolute bliss.**

This means there is nothing which is not Krishna and that cannot be contemplated *as* Krishna. Contemplating him as formless, not limited to one object, we begin to see him. Seeing Krishna in all is to contemplate Krishna.

Carrying this into all of our actions is to serve him in unswerving devotion. To contemplate Krishna is to contemplate the Self and seeing the formless in all form is seeing with the divine eye. Most importantly, this is no different than becoming absorbed in the Self and Brahman. Krishna is the gateway to Brahman.